# Nonmetric TSP and Functional Compleixty Classes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, optimization

Non-metric TSP that is TSP and some instance is not hold the triangle inequality is NP-hard by gap-reduction method.

Is this general TSP a complete problem in some functional complexity classes ?

I've read the zoo, but this problem is not mentioned.

Comment: Are you asking if an optimization problem is complete for a functional complexity class ? I'm not sure why the non-metric aspect comes into play.

Comment: @Suresh: It seems that metric (as well as Euclidean) aspects only come into play, if we are interested in *approximating* TSP (Christofides, Arora, Mitchel, etc.).